# How to write a UML class diagram for a website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, uml

I am writing a graduation report and I thought a UML class would be necessary. I've done UML classes for java projects, but none for HTML yet. I understand that in Java we have the object oriented approach (where we have classes and members), and I am not quite sure on how to do it for an HTML project.

My HTML project (or at least a part of it) is about a website for admins to login to and review data collected from another source.

Maybe some examples would help.

Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: If someone can *log in* on that website and see some data (which is probably not hard-coded in HTML, but retrieved from a database or something like that), you are probably using more than pure HTML. Probably, especially the code written in that *not HTML* part of your website is what should be considered for creating an UML class overview.

Comment: That said, creating a diagram because "there is none yet" is generally a questionable motivation. You should add diagrams when you feel they enhance the understanding of the text, and likewise, you should decide to use a UML class diagram (as opposed to another UML diagram type, or another non-UML diagram type altogether) because you feel it is appropriate, not because of some arbitrary guideline such as "every design document needs to contain two UML class diagrams". Therefore, please make sure *first* whether including a UML class diagram is really a requirement.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for answering my question, it does really have a good point to it. Supposedly, they did require it, how is it done? And yes, it branches out to PHP and some javascripting. Do i still use an Object oriented approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about the UI modelling. It can be divided into several levels.

- Levels from Use Case to Development/components diagrams. Now they are out of the scope of discussion
- Planning the content of UI - what is on a graphic element, what elements belong to this one, what commands/events happens to the element, and what are sequences. No base UI elements (radio buttons, forms) are chosen and not graphic, too. There are NO diagrams supporting this level directly. This is the most important level though. You can use existing diagrams for this alternate use. I use class diagrams - by associations I show what is contained to what and by dependencies arrows - the "moves" by means of commands from elements to other ones. The more difficult is to show the change on one element due to command in another one. I show it as class associations tied to a dependency. It is only my solution, you could look for another one.
- Joining the previous level with the choose of the concrete realization - choice of the concrete base elements. Here you can use the traditional class diagrams, but they are not very complex.
- Drawing the sketches.
- Coding.